# Realtime with AJAX/MySQL multiple variables?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, real-time

I have an dymamic PHP file that load Data from MySQL database about some relay card, every user have a different amount of relay card. All card have 8 relays (State 1/0), 8 inputs (State 1/0), and 2 analogue input (State from 0 to 1024) this is for every card, some user will have 1 and some other can have 8 and i would like to update this data as fast as possible. I have done a PHP script that trigger all relays information for a specific user, in this case this is the user 2.

I think the best way to do what i want as what i have read is to call it from jQuery, but i don't understand how-o update many variable.

Here is the code i have to get the latest state from MySQL.
 Ok here is an update of the code, i have separated completely the data fetching and the GUI creation, so what i want to do, is show in realtime what the get_states_gui.php file fetch from mysql to the gui.php file. Can someone point me in the good direction since i am completely lost right now! THanx a lot here are those 2 files:
The gui.php:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
// We create connection to the MySQL database.
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$con) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }
//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database\n");
    }
$req="SELECT * FROM cartes WHERE utilisateur=$user";
$result = mysql_query($req);
    if(!$result) {
        die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }    
$nb_iplab = mysql_num_rows($result);
$b = "1";
while ($ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($ligne);
    ${'nom'.$b} = $nom;
    ${'mac'.$b} = $mac;
    ${'ip'.$b} = $ip; 
    for ($i=1; $i <= "8"; $i++ )
    {
        //We set Relays names for each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
        ${'nomR'.$i.$b} = ${'nomR'.$i};
        $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='R$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysql_query($req);
            if(!$result2) 
            {
                die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }   
        $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        extract($ligne); 
        ${'stateR'.$i.$b} = $state;
        if ( ${'stateR'.$i.$b} == "1" )
        {
            ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=CR$i target=empty> <img src=img/toggle_1.png height=28></a>";
        }
        else if ( ${'stateR'.$i.$b} == "0" )
        {
            ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=SR$i target=empty> <img src=img/toggle_0.png height=28></a>";
        }
        else
        {
            ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=CR$i target=empty> <img src=img/LED_yellow.png height=28></a>";
        }               
        //We set Inputs names for each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
        ${'nomI'.$i.$b} = ${'nomI'.$i};
        ${'multI'.$i.$b} = ${'multI'.$i};
        ${'img_onI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_onI'.$i};
        ${'img_offI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_offI'.$i};
        ${'img_naI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_naI'.$i};
        $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='I$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysql_query($req);
            if(!$result2) 
            {
                die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }   
        $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        extract($ligne);
        ${'stateI'.$i.$b} = $state;
        if ( ${'stateI'.$i.$b} == "1" )
        {
            ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_onI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
        }
        else if ( ${'stateI'.$i.$b} == "0" )
        {
            ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_offI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
        }
        else
        {
            ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_naI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
        }
        // We check for how many times, the Inputs has changed state to 1, and we set them as a variable for counter.
        $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM states_log WHERE dev='I$i' AND state='1' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($req);
            if(!$result2) 
            {
                die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }   
        list (${'countI'.$i.$b}) = mysql_fetch_row ($result2);
        if (isset(${'multI'.$i.$b}))
        {
            ${'countI'.$i.$b} = ${'countI'.$i.$b} * ${'multI'.$i.$b};
        }

    } 
    //We set Analog names fir each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
    for ($i=1; $i <= "3"; $i++ )
    {
        ${'nomA'.$i.$b} = ${'nomA'.$i};
        ${'unitA'.$i.$b} = ${'unitA'.$i};
        $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='A$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result2 = mysql_query($req);
            if(!$result2) 
            {
                die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }   
        $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
        extract($ligne);
        ${'stateA'.$i.$b} = $state;
    } 
    if ( debug == "1" )
    {
        echo "${'nom'.$b}<br>";
        echo "MAC = ${'mac'.$b}<br>";
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++ )
        {

            echo "${'nomR'.$i.$b} = ${'stateR'.$i.$b}<br>";
            echo "${'nomI'.$i.$b} = ${'stateI'.$i.$b}<br>";
        }
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ )
    {
        echo "${'nomA'.$i.$b} = ${'stateA'.$i.$b}<br>";
    }
        echo "---------------------------------------<br>";
    }
    $b++;
    }

$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
if ( debug == "1" )
    {
        echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.'."\n";
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And now the get_states_gui.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once('config.php');
    $time = microtime();
    $time = explode(' ', $time);
    $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
    $start = $time;
    // We create connection to the MySQL database.
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        if(!$con) {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
        if(!$db) {
            die("Unable to select database\n");
        }
    $req="SELECT * FROM cartes WHERE utilisateur=$user";
    $result = mysql_query($req);
        if(!$result) {
            die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        }    
    $nb_iplab = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $b = "1";
    while ($ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        extract($ligne);
        ${'nom'.$b} = $nom;
        ${'mac'.$b} = $mac;
        ${'ip'.$b} = $ip;
        for ($i=1; $i <= "8"; $i++ )
        {
            //We set Relays names for each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
            ${'nomR'.$i.$b} = ${'nomR'.$i};
            $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='R$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result2 = mysql_query($req);
                if(!$result2) 
                {
                    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                }   
            $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            extract($ligne); 
            ${'stateR'.$i.$b} = $state;
            if ( ${'stateR'.$i.$b} == "1" )
            {
                ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=CR$i target=empty> <img src=img/toggle_1.png height=28></a>";
            }
            else if ( ${'stateR'.$i.$b} == "0" )
            {
                ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=SR$i target=empty> <img src=img/toggle_0.png height=28></a>";
            }
            else
            {
                ${'img_linkR'.$i.$b} = "<a href=set_states.php?ip=${'ip'.$b}&cmd=CR$i target=empty> <img src=img/LED_yellow.png height=28></a>";
            }               
            //We set Inputs names for each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
            ${'nomI'.$i.$b} = ${'nomI'.$i};
            ${'multI'.$i.$b} = ${'multI'.$i};
            ${'img_onI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_onI'.$i};
            ${'img_offI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_offI'.$i};
            ${'img_naI'.$i.$b} = ${'img_naI'.$i};
            $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='I$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result2 = mysql_query($req);
                if(!$result2) 
                {
                    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                }   
            $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            extract($ligne);
            ${'stateI'.$i.$b} = $state;
            if ( ${'stateI'.$i.$b} == "1" )
            {
                ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_onI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
            }
            else if ( ${'stateI'.$i.$b} == "0" )
            {
                ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_offI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
            }
            else
            {
                ${'img_linkI'.$i.$b} = "<img src=img/${'img_naI'.$i.$b} height=28>";
            }
            // We check for how many times, the Inputs has changed state to 1, and we set them as a variable for counter.
            $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM states_log WHERE dev='I$i' AND state='1' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($req);
                if(!$result2) 
                {
                    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                }   
            list (${'countI'.$i.$b}) = mysql_fetch_row ($result2);
            if (isset(${'multI'.$i.$b}))
            {
                ${'countI'.$i.$b} = ${'countI'.$i.$b} * ${'multI'.$i.$b};
            }

        } 
        //We set Analog names fir each IPLAB and get their states in the MySQL database.
        for ($i=1; $i <= "3"; $i++ )
        {
            ${'nomA'.$i.$b} = ${'nomA'.$i};
            ${'unitA'.$i.$b} = ${'unitA'.$i};
            $req = "SELECT * FROM states_log WHERE dev='A$i' AND mac='${'mac'.$b}' ORDER BY date_heure DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result2 = mysql_query($req);
                if(!$result2) 
                {
                    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                }   
            $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            extract($ligne);
            ${'stateA'.$i.$b} = $state;
        } 
        if ( debug == "1" )
        {
            echo "${'nom'.$b}<br>";
            echo "MAC = ${'mac'.$b}<br>";
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++ )
            {

                echo "${'nomR'.$i.$b} = ${'stateR'.$i.$b}<br>";
                echo "${'nomI'.$i.$b} = ${'stateI'.$i.$b}<br>";
            }
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ )
        {
            echo "${'nomA'.$i.$b} = ${'stateA'.$i.$b}<br>";
        }
            echo "---------------------------------------<br>";
        }
        $b++;
        }

    $time = microtime();
    $time = explode(' ', $time);
    $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
    $finish = $time;
    $total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
    if ( debug == "1" )
        {
            echo 'Page generated in '.$total_time.' seconds.'."\n";
        }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

I can give access to the source, MySQL etc if someone can help, i am learning right now, And i really enjoy how it goes for now, but the AJAX Jquery thing, i completely miss it!!

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could wright more of an abstract question ... no need for php code ...
If i understood you right , you need to send ajax reqests on a specific time interval to get your updated data ( js function setInterval() )
Here is a link about setInterval : http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/
Here is link about ajax : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
If this answer has nothing to do with your question , please review it and state what you want to do with your data? Show it on each update? or what kind of update?

Comment: @ MARX B W3cshools get's right to the point and its very well organised...thats why i linked that ... i never spoted any wrong information there... maybe some outdated... but they still do work

Comment: Yes in fact i am really new to AJAX but learn pretty fast from exemple! What i want to do is execute the above php phile at 1 second interval and update all the information in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could use javascript to trriger ajax script after 1 sec delay use setTimeout() in javascript for delay And in your php page retrieve the data and echo it.
```

Comment: Are you willing to helpme out on this one, to be honest i am not a big JAVA programmer and i learn pretty fast with exemple. i can give webdav access to the source coe if you wish.?